# get parameters from aws lambda post request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, twilio

I'm trying to receive a POST from a twilio widget, but my aws lambda (nodejs) function fails.

```
{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token \'RecordingSource\': was expecting (\'true\', \'false\' or \'null\')\n at [Source: (byte[])\"RecordingSource=RecordVerb&RecordingSid=REd9475d9sdfw616e81995366d5f02291506b0&RecordingUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twilio.com%2F2010-04-01%2FAccounts%2FAC87e46c891a699385%2FRecordings%2FREd9466d5f02291506b0&RecordingStatus=completed&RecordingChannels=1&ErrorCode=0&CallSid=CA4a7f45753ef87894245dc95d445d8672&RecordingStartTime=Sat%2C%2021%20Mar%202020%2014%3A50%3A32%20%2B0000&AccountSid=AC8799385&RecordingDuration=2\"; line: 1, column: 17]"}
```

My AWS lambda function is very simple.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {

  console.log('-------------------------');
  console.log(event);
  console.log('-------------------------');
```

Comment: Your twilio widget is sending in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but your server is attempting to handle `application/json`.  To send json instead is a client side configuration, and your widget will have to support such a configuration.

Comment: JSON is a configurable option for the Twilio Studio HTTP Request Widget - https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request (Content Type).

Comment: it's the record voicemail widget

Comment: Ah, then that will use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format and there is not a way to change it to `application/json`, https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-faq.

Comment: got it. can I somehow send the recording from the http widget instead? instead of sending directly from the voice recording widget

Comment: You could use a serverless Twilio Functions which will parse the parameters for you, https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions, and then perform some action.

Comment: Really, you could set the Recording Status Callback to a Twilio Function URL, which can do what you need it to do. Twilio Functions uses Node/JavaScript.

Comment: Twilio Functions You Tube Playlist - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8s8cwjh4_7Q&list=PLqrz4nXepkz6fX9ynQpCqgScE8wmPE9VY

Comment: do you know how long twilio stores recordings for?

Comment: Forever, until you delete them - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132527-How-much-does-it-cost-to-record-a-call-

Comment: awesome. thanks! @DanielFarrell add official response so I can accept?

Answer (score 0):

Your twilio widget is sending in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but your server is attempting to handle `application/json`. To send json instead is a client side configuration, and your widget will have to support such a configuration.

As @Alan suggests,

> you could set the Recording Status Callback to a Twilio Function URL, which can do what you need it to do. Twilio Functions uses Node/JavaScript.